# Inline script conditional statement inside a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to display an image inside a ListView control based on the value of a databound property. I've tried two methods of doing this (one at a time) and both returned errors of "The server tag is not well formed". Consider the code below.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="left">

    <!-- Method 1 -->
    <img src="media-play-button.png" alt="Play" class="mediaplay noborder" runat="server" visible="<%# Eval("MediaType").ToString() == "video" %>" />

    <!-- Method 2 -->
    <%# if (((MediaLink)Container.DataItem).MediaType == "video") { %>
    <img src="media-play-button.png" alt="Play" class="mediaplay noborder" />
    <%# } %>

    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method 1**:

Instead of using `"` for the `visible` attribute value, use `'`:

```
<img src="media-play-button.png" alt="Play" class="mediaplay noborder" 
    runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("MediaType").ToString() == "video" %>' />
```

Using `"` causes the string to terminate after `<%# Eval(`.

**Method 2**:

Don't use binding expressions (`<%#%>`) for coding blocks (`<%%>`):

```
<% if (((MediaLink)Container.DataItem).MediaType == "video") { %>
<img src="media-play-button.png" alt="Play" class="mediaplay noborder" />
<% } %>
```